# Is there a way to separately get the Program Files output for Visual Studio setup projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-project

In a Visual Studio setup project, you define a Program Files output (amongst other things of course).

Is there any way to output this to a folder directly, i.e. get that output without actually building and installing the msi to Windows?

What I am looking for is something similar to the "File System" publish method for web projects.

Alternatively, I could do with a "portable install" option in the msi (similar for instance to the Firefox portable install), or an switch in msiexec (I did not find anything like this in the documentation), or a way to extract this folder structure from the msi via a third-party tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Administrative Installation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You run a postbuild command like:

```
msiexec /a "$(TargetPath)" /qn TARGETDIR="$(OutDir)\Extract"
```

Please note that I didn't test that command but that's the general concept.  This will extract your MSI to a directory.

Comment: That seems to work, do you know why msiexec also outputs the msi file into the folder?

Comment: It serves as an installation point from a workgroup.  It's not needed for your purposes and you can ignore it or delete it.